Solving Euler-Lagrange system describing propagation of light through a medium with a varying index of refraction
Background.
I'm attempting to compute the path taken by a ray of light propagating between two points in a medium whose index of refraction is a function of depth of the form:
$$A - B e^{Cz}$$
...for some constants $A,B$ and $C$. I know that this is (in principle) a relatively straightforward calculus of variations problem, however I've encountered some difficulty in working through the algebraic complexities of the solution. I expect that there is some simpler way to approach this. I've been following in part this answer to a similar Math.SE question.
What I have so far.
Notice first that, since the index of refraction is a function only of depth, that this can be reduced to a two-dimensional problem in $x$ and $z$ alone. I begin by parametrizing the equations for $x$ and $z$ by $s$, so that $x = x(s)$ and $z = z(s)$. By Fermat's principle, the optical path length is given by the minimum of:
$$L = \int_{\textrm{path}} n(z)ds$$
The Euler-Lagrange equations for the path of least time are given by:
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial z} = \frac{d}{ds}\left( n\frac{dz}{ds} \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial x} = \frac{d}{ds}\left( n\frac{dx}{ds} \right)$$
For our particular form of $n$, the Euler-Lagrange equations become:
$$B C e^{C z} = \frac{d}{ds}\left( (A - B\cdot e^{Cz}) \frac{dz}{ds}\right)$$
$$0 = \frac{d}{ds}\left( (A - B\cdot e^{Cz}) \frac{dx}{ds}\right)$$

Simplifying the First Euler-Lagrange Equation.
For the RHS, the product rule gives:
$$\frac{d}{ds}\left( (A - B\cdot e^{Cz}) \frac{dz}{ds}\right) = (A - Be^{Cz}) \times \frac{d}{ds}\frac{dz}{ds} + \frac{dz}{ds} \times \frac{d}{ds}(A - Be^{Cz})$$
Which simplifies to:
$$(A - Be^{Cz}) z'' - (z')^2 BCe^{Cz}$$
...where a primed function denotes its derivative with respect to $s$. So the first Euler-Lagrange equation becomes:
$$-BCe^{Cz} = (A - Be^{Cz}) z'' - (z')^2 BCe^{Cz}$$
Dividing across by $-BCe^{Cz}$, we obtain:
$$\boxed{1 = \frac{A - Be^{Cz}}{BCe^{Cz}}z'' + (z')^2  = \left( \frac{A}{BCe^{Cz}} - 1\right)z'' + (z')^2}$$

Simplifying the Second Euler-Lagrange Equation.
Notice that we follow effectively the same steps, ultimately obtaining (I believe) the same result save for replacing $z$ and $z'$ by $x$ and $x'$:
$$\boxed{0 = \left(\frac{A}{BCe^{Cz}}-1\right)x'' + (x')^2}$$
Problem.
Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried passing this to various differential equation solvers, to no avail. For a number of reasons I would like to obtain an analytic solution, as opposed to solving this numerically.
How do I solve this system of differential equations?

(Edit:) An Idea
Note that what follows was very quickly sketched out, and might contain (read: most likely contains) some dumb math errors
I'll start instead with @Semiclassical's suggestion to write the optical path length as follows, in an attempt to avoid the arc-length parameterization:
$$L = \int_a^b n(z)s'(z)dz = \int_a^b n(z)\sqrt{1 + x'(z)^2}dz$$
The Lagrangian is then:
$$\mathcal{L} = n(z)\sqrt{1 + (x')^2}$$
The Euler-Lagrange equation gives:
$$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x'}\right) = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dz}\left( n(z)\frac{x'}{\sqrt{1+(x')^2}} \right) = 0 \implies n(z)\frac{x'}{\sqrt{1+(x')^2}}  = C_1$$
...which can be re-arranged to obtain:
$$\frac{x'}{\sqrt{1+(x')^2}} = \frac{C_1}{n(z)} \implies \frac{(x')^2}{1+(x')^2} = \frac{C_1^2}{n^2(z)} \implies (x')^2 = \frac{C_1^2}{n^2(z) - C_1^2}$$
Hence:
$$x' = \pm \frac{C_1}{\sqrt{n^2(z) - C_1^2}} \implies x(z) = \pm\int \frac{C_1}{\sqrt{n^2(z) - C_1^2}}dz + C_2$$
It is clear (I think) that $C_2$ is the $x$ coordinate of the initial point $a$ in the original integral $L$. I haven't yet worked out how to determine $C_1$... it looks like it might be a bit messy. So thus far maybe this works (?):
$$\boxed{x(z) = \pm\int \frac{C_1}{\sqrt{n^2(z) - C_1^2}}dz + x(a)} = \pm\; C_1\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(A - Be^{Cz})^2 - C_1^2}}dz + x(a)$$
I've tried quickly putting the above into a couple of integral solvers, but haven't yet tried evaluating anything by hand. One gave me:
$$-\frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{2C_{1}^{2} \mathrm{e}^{-Cz}}{\sqrt{4A^{2} B^{2} - 4B^{2} \left(A^{2} - C_{1}^{2}\right)}} - \frac{2A^{2} \mathrm{e}^{-Cz}}{\sqrt{4A^{2} B^{2} - 4B^{2} \left(A^{2} - C_{1}^{2}\right)}} + \frac{2AB}{\sqrt{4A^{2} B^{2} - 4B^{2} \left(A^{2} - C_{1}^{2}\right)}}\right)}{C \sqrt{C_{1}^{2} - A^{2}}}$$
...another gave me:
$$\frac{1}{Ck} \ln \left| \frac{Be^{Cz} + \sqrt{(Be^{Cz})^2 + A^2 - C_1^2}}{A^2 - C_1^2} \right|\;\;\;\;\;\;\textrm{  } \;\;\;\;\; k^2 = A^2 - C_1^2$$

Note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}s} = z'' \neq z'$.

One way to bypass the arc-length parametrization is to rewrite the optical path length as $L=\int_a^b n(z)s'(z)~dz=\int_a^b n(z)\sqrt{1+x'(z)^2}dz$. The Euler-Lagrange equations will obviously be worse, but now there's only one variable.

It is easier to come back to the initial Euler-Lagrange equations, namely
$$
\begin{cases}
   \displaystyle
   \frac{\partial n}{\partial z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(n\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}s}\right) \\
   \displaystyle
   \frac{\partial n}{\partial x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}s}\right)
\end{cases}
$$
The first equation leads to an independent differential equation for the variable $z = z(s)$, which has to be solved first, while the second one will allow to determine the variable $x = x(s)$ from $z$. Indeed, given that $\frac{\partial n}{\partial x} = 0$, the latter is integrated as
$$
x(s) = \alpha + \beta\int\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{n(z)} = \alpha + \beta\int\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{A-Be^{Cz(s)}},
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants of integration.
Now, the first equation can be simplified by considering $n$ as the main variable instead of $z$ $-$ in other words, by making the change of variable $z \mapsto n(z) = A-Be^{Cz}$. Then, one has $\frac{\partial n}{\partial z} = -BCe^{Cz} = C(n-A)$, as well as $\frac{\mathrm{d}n}{\mathrm{d}s} = n(z)\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}s}$ due to the chain rule. In consequence, the first differential equation can be rewritten as $n''(s) = C(n(s)-A)$, which is solved by $n(s) = A + \gamma e^{\sqrt{C}s} + \delta e^{-\sqrt{C}s}$, with $\gamma$ and $\delta$ some constants of integration, hence finally
$$
z(s) = \frac{1}{C}\ln\left(\frac{n(s)-A}{-B}\right) = \frac{1}{C}\ln\left(-\frac{\gamma}{B}e^{\sqrt{C}s}-\frac{\delta}{B}e^{-\sqrt{C}s}\right).
$$
You might reparametrize this solution as $z(s) = \frac{1}{C}\ln\left(\tilde{\gamma}\cosh(\sqrt{C}s) + \tilde{\delta}\sinh(\sqrt{C}s)\right)$ for convenience.

Based on the result for $n(s)$, one could  continue the calculation of $x(s)$ as $$x(s)=\alpha+\beta\int\frac{ds}{A+\gamma e^{\sqrt{C}s}+\Delta e^{-\sqrt{C}s} \sqrt{C}s}=\alpha+\frac{2\beta}{\sqrt{C}\sqrt{ 4\gamma \delta-A^2}}\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{A+2e^{\sqrt{C}s}}{\sqrt{ 4\gamma \delta-A^2}}\right] $$ But this expression seems a bit too laborious to provide much insight.

Thanks! That's a clever change of variables. Determining $\alpha$ and $\beta$ seems fairly straightforward. Is it possible to solve for $\gamma$ and $\delta$ given just the known boundary conditions (namely, the initial and final points of the ray $(x_0, z_0)$ and $(x_1, z_1)$, and thereby $n(z=z_0)$, $n(z=z_1)$, $z(s=0)$, and $x(s=0)$)? I think we can also say that $n(z=z_0) = n(s=0)$. I can't seem to work out formulae for $\delta$ and $\gamma$, although maybe my algebra is just bad.
